# How to put diffrent size container elements next to each other HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

How do we put small boxes (on the right) next to the big box (on the left)? I tried using ***float: left;*** in CSS but its not working!?
Thanks in advance!
Here is the CSS and HTML:

```css
.container1{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 170px;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  margin: 10px;
}


.container-fluid{
  float: right;
  padding-left: 320px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

h1{
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;

}

.uiBox{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
<aside>
<div class="uiBox" data-search-type="category/tree">
  <ul class="categories">
    <li class="category-001">
      <a href="/listing" title="Text" class="text"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</aside>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"></div>
  <div class="container1 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

[image]

Comment: It would help if you posted your code

Comment: Hey, just added

Comment: Consider using `display: flex; flex-direction: row;` and work from there

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: It would also help if you posted the CSS as well

Comment: Yes using Bootstrap, just added the CSS as well

Comment: You should the Bootstrap tag to attract the right people

Answer (score 0):

It fits like this

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="uiBox" data-search-type="category/tree" class="col-xs-4">
    <ul class="categories">
      <li class="category-001">
        <a href="/listing" title="Text" class="text"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container1 col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="container1 col-xs-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: and how should CSS look like in this case? as it completely masses up everything on my end

Comment: you don't have to touch css actually .D